# How to Loop an Array Using Map Function Based on Condition and Then setState?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, array.prototype.map

I want to have same functionality using map function. Following is my code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
const data = await TodoAPI.getTodo();
      for(var i=0;i<data.response.length;i++)
      {
        if(data.response[i]._id === this.props.match.params.id)
            {
                this.setState({
                todo_description: data.response[i].todo_description,
                todo_responsible: data.response[i].todo_responsible,
                todo_priority: data.response[i].todo_priority,
                todo_completed: data.response[i].todo_completed
                })
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you are expecting anything less than all of the `response` array to match the `params.id`, then you do not want to use `map`. Map returns a new array by running a callback function against each element in the array. Perhaps you want to use `filter` instead? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

I guess you’re a bit confused, as `map()` would not be useful in this case. It creates a new array but what you want (correct me if I’m wrong) is to find the item, so `find()` seems to be what you need:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const data = await TodoAPI.getTodo();
  const id = this.props.match.params.id;
  const item = data.response.find(item => item._id === id);
  this.setState(item);
}
```

Comment: ```filter``` also creates an array, so ```item``` is an array.

Comment: @JuniusL. Ups, you're totally right! Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.